# Ссылка на .svg изображение

Tags: url, svg, браузер

Имеется ссылка на картинку формата .svg ('http://en-mile.ru/upload/iblock/215/2156f974bc6fba7d3750322ada59138c.svg') При переходе по ссылке белый экран, но страница сожержит код.

**Вопрос:** как мне получить картинку, может произвести какието манипуляции с кодом или использовать необходимые библиотеки. Или же ее получить невозможно и я что то попутал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

это не *html*-страница, это файл.

судя по всему, он содержит внутри себя изображение в формате [svg](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) типа «белый квадрат».

вот вам браузер и показывает «белый квадрат на белом фоне».

Answer (score 3):

> судя по всему, он содержит внутри себя изображение в формате svg типа
>   «белый квадрат».
>
> вот вам браузер и показывает «белый квадрат на белом фоне

Обратите внимание на строки кода в исходном файле SVG:

```
fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF"
```

Заливки нет, линии белого цвета, поэтому и не видно.
Изменил на - stroke="black" и увеличил масштаб через **viewport - width="96px" height="96px" и viewBox="0 0 12 12"**, а то слишком мелко было/

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="96px" height="96px" viewBox="0 0 12 12" >
<circle fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="5.485" cy="5.506" r="1.945"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="2.229" y1="5.506" x2="0.324" y2="5.506"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="10.687" y1="5.506" x2="8.782" y2="5.506"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="5.505" y1="8.782" x2="5.505" y2="10.687"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="5.505" y1="0.324" x2="5.505" y2="2.229"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="2.896" y1="8.115" x2="2.283" y2="8.728"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="8.697" y1="2.314" x2="8.114" y2="2.897"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="8.113" y1="8.115" x2="8.781" y2="8.783"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="2.291" y1="2.292" x2="2.896" y2="2.897"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Sevastopol' я видел. Немного будет посвободней, пообщаемся с ним. В принципе любой вопрос можно сделать дубликатом. Было бы желание.

Answer (score 2):

Это svg file в нем содержится следующее

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="11.011px" height="11.011px" viewBox="0 0 11.011 11.011" enable-background="new 0 0 11.011 11.011" xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="5.485" cy="5.506" r="1.945"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="2.229" y1="5.506" x2="0.324" y2="5.506"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="10.687" y1="5.506" x2="8.782" y2="5.506"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="5.505" y1="8.782" x2="5.505" y2="10.687"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="5.505" y1="0.324" x2="5.505" y2="2.229"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="2.896" y1="8.115" x2="2.283" y2="8.728"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="8.697" y1="2.314" x2="8.114" y2="2.897"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="8.113" y1="8.115" x2="8.781" y2="8.783"/>
<line fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.648" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="2.291" y1="2.292" x2="2.896" y2="2.897"/>
</svg>
```

Как мы видим это набор кругов и  линий белого цвета.
Вы уже получили доступ к картинки.